# try to delete using checkbox all, and receive error

Tags: javascript, rails-activerecord

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/>Select All</label>
<td><input class="chk" type="checkbox"/>Option 1</td>
<td><input class="chk" type="checkbox"/>Option 2</td>
<td><input class="chk" type="checkbox"/>Option 3</td>
<td><input class="chk" type="checkbox"/>Option 4</td>
<td><input class="chk" type="checkbox"/>Option 5</td>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#select_all").change(function(){
     $(".chk").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
</script>
```

After I select all using checkbox's i use my 'trash' to delete
js.coffee

```
 switch $(@).val()
      when "trash"
        _test = []
        $('#read_messages_table :checkbox:checked').each ->
          _test.push($(@).closest('tr').data('id'))
        $.post('/file/trash', test: _test).success (data) ->
          location.reload()
```

controller

```
def trash
params[:test].each do |n|
_test = Test.find(n)
_test.box = 'trash'
_test.save!
end
end
```

If i use button, everything work fine, but I don't want to use a button, I want to use a input for select all

So, select all checkbox's is working, but if I use select all from checkbox, don't work and give this undefined index
I think he try to use the first index of checkbox, this one,

is possible to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your "chk" class

So in your file  delete js.coffee, when your write the each code, just add `checkbox.chk:checked`